# JSON в PostgreSQL 9.6, извлечь определенные значения по любым ключам

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Мне надо, чтобы скрипт брал любой ключ.  Вот так пробовал не работает:

```sql
select * from payments
where provider_id = '1295'
and options::json->>'%%' = 'Инженерно - техническое заключение'
```

Примеры полей (таких много):

```json
{"alma": "gana"}
{"yama": "Инженерно - техническое заключение"}
{"almaz": "ganat"}
{"fkda": "Инженерно - техническое заключение"}
{"kanat": "jannat"}
{"sad434": "Инженерно - техническое заключение"}
```

Надо вывести только те значения, у которых значение равно `'Инженерно - техническое заключение'`, вне зависимости от ключа.

Comment: Приведите полные примеры _JSON_-объектов.

Comment: И уточните версию _PostgreSQL._  В 12 значительно улучшена работа с `JSONB`.

Answer (score 1):

(Я всё же предположу, что в заголовке у вас ошибка, и имеется в виду
*PostgreSQL* версии **9.6**, потому что в 5.6 про
*JSON* даже и не думали.)

Похоже на работу для функции `json_each_text` в сочетании
с *боковым перекрёстным соединением* (англ. «*lateral cross
join*»):

```sql
SELECT payments.*
  FROM payments
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT * FROM json_each_text(payments.options)
       ) AS options
 WHERE provider_id = '1295'
   AND options.value = 'Инженерно - техническое заключение'
;
```

Более коротко, но менее стандартно:

```sql
SELECT payments.*
  FROM payments
     , json_each_text(payments.options) AS options
 WHERE provider_id = '1295'
   AND options.value = 'Инженерно - техническое заключение'
;
```

*DBFiddle*: 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qBjtdLpbMAHpgSg9dHuHSM/0

Comment: можно проще `AND 'Инженерно - техническое заключение' in (select value FROM json_each_text(payments.options))`